# How to 'merge/dissolve' two faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, faces

I had trouble merging/dissolve two faces together, like merging these two faces in the screenshot. Any help is appreciated :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you upload your blendfile?

Comment: if F and Limited dissolve don't work you might want to share the .blend because I think you might have some unusual (accidental) geometry you aren't aware of.

Comment: @Mr.Benson to mark it as solved you have to accept the right answer using the check mark on the left of the answer ( not by writing solved )

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the <kbd>F</kbd> key, this joins any selected faces if it makes sense topologically.

[image]

But, you will get an Ngon on that face.

Comment: Nothing happens when I press F

Comment: This is what the F key does: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html#modeling-mesh-deleting-dissolve-faces

Comment: That merges the faces, but keeps all the excess vertexes...

Answer (score 21):

- Go to edge select in edit mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Tab</kbd> --> ***EDGE***),
- select the middle edge of the two faces.
- Then <kbd>X</kbd> --> ***dissolve edges***

Comment: you do not have to be in edge mode for that to work, just select the middle face, then "dissolve edges"

Comment: The object became corrupted like the second screenshot after I dissolved the middle edge.

Comment: this just breaks the object