# Two faces sharing same four vertices issues

Tags: faces

I have an issue with this model having two faces that share the same four vertices. I have tried merging vertices but that didn't fix it since there are only four vertices. I can delete one face no issue and the other remains in place. However to fix the model and delete faces one by one would be a huge task.

Can you please take a look and let me know if you have any suggestions?

[Blend File](https://1drv.ms/u/s!At0tQ0s2FFP75cBOaWbVrrWwHSJe4w?e=iuOGtR)

Comment: You cannot merge them because that is a bug in Blender which I have logged, and it got merged with this ticket https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/70977. See this thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282322/is-having-2-or-more-faces-with-all-shared-vertices-a-bug-or-valid-geometry. Unfortuntely you have to manually delete the faces one by one or you could write a python script that detects if 2 faces share the same 4 vertices and deletes one of the faces.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing the links and your help Harry. Much appreciated.

Comment: This workaround in Answer No 3 worked and have now managed to removed all the double face in the mesh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183795/two-faces-inside-of-each-other-sharing-same-4-vertices-why-and-how-to-fix  Tanks to all for your input.

Answer (score 6):

Open the Python console and enter

```
for m in D.meshes: m.validate()
```

This should fix all the meshes in your file (you may need to click on something to update the UI). You may also need to recalculate normals afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not familiar using the Python console. I did try your script however it resulted in a lot of holes in mesh.  Is there some parameters I need to add to this script to control the output? Or is there a shortcut I can use that does the same?

Comment: Ah it works after you select the object then it updates the view. very nice solution +1

Comment: Wow. Never come across this. I wonder why it's not exposed as an operator, somewhere? Or is it?

Comment: @RobinBetts coz its a workaround and not supposed to be necessary since the double-faced geometry is a bug. i have a thread where i reproduced this issue (up to 20 faces sharing the same 4 vertices haha) and a bug report.